# Do i need sort the data by the eigenvalues with descend (PCA)

Tags: pca

after computing the eigenvectors and eigenvalues.
the eigenvectors sort by eigenvalues on descending.

data * eigenvectors = transformed data

how about the standardized raw data, do I need to sort them by the eigenvalues too?

before calculating the transformed data.

or are they just the same result?